# Whats the best way to display a progress bar at the start of calculations then hide it at the end

Tags: android

..without putting the calculation code into an asyncTask but the progress logic can be in an asynctask

Im looking for something like this

```
 onCreate(){
    ShowProgressBar()
    ...
    do many operations
    ....
    hidePogressBar()
```

I've tried putting the progress bar in an async task but it's complaining that it belongs to a different thread. and even if it worked, there is no way of stopping it once it starts in `doInBackground()` unless I hide it at the `onPostExecute()` which means it will disappear as soon as it starts because there is nothing in `doInBackground()`

How can I do this?

Comment: If there is nothing in `doInBackground`, then what is the progress bar supposed to represent?

Comment: also you should not be starting the dialog in the `doInBackground` you should be starting it in the `onPreExecute`

Comment: @simon it will represent the loading of all the stuff in onCreate()

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to put the calculation logic in `AsyncTask`? It may help for us to find a better way. You can call `Activity` methods from `AsyncTask`

Comment: I suggest that onCreate() should not be doing anything heavy.  Start up a thread from oncreate and do all of the loading, and controlling the progress bar, in there.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried putting the progress bar in an async task but it's complaining that it belongs to a different thread.

Post the logcat from that and we can help figure out what is going wrong

> there is no way of stopping it once it starts in doInBackground() unless I hide it at the onPostExecute() which means it will disappear as soon as it starts because there is nothing in doInBackground()

If there is no work to be done then there would be no point of having a `ProgressDialog`. 
Put whatever work you are doing in the `doInBackground()` then it will call `onPostExecute()` and you can `dismiss()` your `ProgressBar` from there

Show your progress bar in `onPreExecute()`